# Make Mysql Partial tolerance

Tags: mysql

I have read somewhere, By Cap theorm

```
RDBMS is CA
MONGO is CP
CASSANDRA is AP
```

However we can tune any database to get any 2.

Can anyone explain how can i tune Mysql to be CP or AP ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before giving the answer, This is a brief of CAP theorem.

> **Consistency** - All active nodes gave the same data
>
> **Availability** means the ability to access the cluster even if a node in the cluster goes down.
>
> **Partition tolerance** means that the cluster continues to function even if there is a "partition" (communication break) between two nodes
> (both nodes are up, but can't communicate).

For Mysql to be AP, we can use a master-master configuration

> **Availability** : Even if one of the masters goes down, the active master can serve the traffic.
>
> **Partition tolerance**: Even if the communication goes down, the writes can be done on both the database and they will eventually
> become consistent when communication comes back. Note: The application
> needs to be smart for handling such cases.